# Finite difference explicit method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, mathematical-modeling

I try to solve with matlab program the differential equation with finite difference explicit method. The problem sounds in this way: **Using finite difference explicit and implicit finite difference method solve problem** $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}=\frac{\partial^2{u}}{\partial{t}}+x-t$ with initial condition: $u(0,x)=sin(x)$ and boundary conditions: $u(t,0)=e^t$, $u(t,1)=e^tsin{1}$. Do this task with mathematical package. So, I tried but get struggles and really need advises. Even I'm not sure how to describe this differential equation or choose number of time steps/space steps in Matlab. Here is what I have tried:

```
L = 1.; % Length of the wire
T =1; % Final time
% Parameters needed to solve the equation within the explicit method
maxk = 50; % Number of time steps
dt = T/maxk;
n = 10; % Number of space steps
dx = L/n;
a = 1; 
b = 2.*a*dt/(dx*dx); 
% Initial temperature of the wire: a sinus.
for i = 1:n+1
x(i) =(i-1)*dx;
u(i,1) =sin(x(i));
end
% Temperature at the boundary
for t=1:maxk+1
u(1,t) = exp(t);
u(n+1,t) = sin(1)*exp(t);
time(t) = (t-1)*dt;
end
% Implementation of the explicit method
for t=1:maxk % Time Loop
for i=2:n; % Space Loop
u(i,t+1) =u(i,t) + b*(u(i-1,t)+u(i+1,t)-2.*u(i,t));
end
end

% Graphical representation of the temperature at different selected times
figure(1)
plot(x,u(:,1),'-',x,u(:,10),'-',x,u(:,45),'-',x,u(:,30),'-',x,u(:,60),'-')
title('Temperature within the explicit method')
xlabel('X')
ylabel('T')
figure(2)
mesh(x,time,u')
title('Temperature within the explicit method')
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Temperature')
```

Comment: If you are starting to study the Finite Difference Method, you should go by parts. There is a lot going on in this (apparently) easy equation. First, there is spatial discretization, related to the term $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$. There is also time discretization, related to $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$. If you are not understanding the equation _"Even I'm not sure how to describe this differential equation"_, then you should tackle easier problems first and later this one.
You should clarify what are your questions

Comment: Do you know how to treat the spatial derivative? How to discretize the second order spatial term? How to apply boundary conditions? How to solve the resultant linear system of the discretized equation? If so, you can move on to the next step. Do you know how to treat the time derivative? Do you know the differences between an implicit and an explicit scheme? What order for the time derivative do you want to use?

Comment: You see, there are more questions and a lot of different ways to tackle the problem than just "help me on solving this equation". A lot of introductory books will cover most of what I just cited. Do you have any good references? Please, help us help you. Be precise on what you are asking and what is not working.